# Deserializing an ArrayList with multiple objects

Tags: java, arraylist, deserialization

I have stored multiple objects in Teacher `ArrayList` and I'm trying to deserialize it, but it shows the garbage value.

```
public void Write(){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("S.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(teachers);

        os.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {System.out.println(e);}

}


public void Read(){
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\Books\\OOP\\Teacher\\S.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        teachers = (ArrayList<Teacher>) ois.readObject();
        for(Teacher i: teachers){
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Error");
        return;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println("Class not found");

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage value"? Does your `Teacher` class override `toString`?

Comment: something like *&%#&&^$5

Comment: Does that come from reading your file directly? Because despite being a ".txt" file, it's being written in binary.

Comment: What is the `toString` method of your `Teacher`class ?

Comment: yes, but if I check in the directory. it also has the same value *#$%@$*

Comment: I used it, my output will be in string because I have stored String values

Comment: What is the output of  `System.out.println(new Teacher());` ?

Comment: txt file is storing this `¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   
w   
sr StudentäÿêÖuð L Namet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using object streams, which persist your serialized objects in binary, regardless of the extension of the file (which happens to be ".txt" here, ambiguously suggesting that it'll be a text file when written).

You cannot view anything human-like from your file with a text editor when the data written is binary data.

If your "garbage values" also get printed when you iterate your `List<Teacher>` upon de-serialization, it implies that:

1. (De-)serialization actually succeeded (i.e. you've written your `List<Teacher>` to file and retrieved it)
2. Your `Teacher` class might not override `toString` properly or at all, so it prints the `Type@hashCode` notation from `Object#toString` when fed to the system output print stream